# how to reformat DateTime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that it is possible to reformat the DateTime data type of the current date and time by using select convert. However, I havent been able to find a method to reformat an existing column (DateTime data type) to: hh:mm:ss yyyy/mm/dd. Or even better, I would like to reformat it to show time only. I dont want to simply convert to time data type because I am working with a chart that accepts either Date or Date time. But what I really want to display on that specific axis of the chart is time. Is there any way to reformat DateTime to my requirements? Thanks.

Comment: Date formatting should be handled by the client, not in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server's `convert` function can take an optional `style` argument depending upon the datatype.  This is how you can get a datetime converted to a string in a variety of formats.  For example, try running:

```
select convert(varchar(30), getdate(), 108) -- returns hh:mi:ss
```

You can replace `getdate()` in this example with a column name as well.

There are many styles available, as shown in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Note that you will be returning a varchar, so you may want to sort by the original column's datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SET DATEFORMAT` but this will change all DateTime's on your SQL Server.  You can do some custom formatting, but it will convert the DateTime into a VarChar, so you won't be able to treat it as a DateTime.

SET DATEFORMAT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

I'm not sure if you will be able to use the format you're asking about, though.